# Return array from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, managed-c++

I want to transfer a struct array from my c++ code (pointer to struct..) to my c# code.

As a first step have I successfully transferred a single struct as a return value in my code using dll inport:

The Struct "Result" containes int, int, and double

C# code:
    [dllimport(...)]
    static extern Result GetResults();

Next I tried to pass a Results Array and I Failed:

```
[dllimport(...)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] - i have tried without this line too
static extern Result GetResults();
```

The exception is:

```
cannot marshal 'return value' invalid managed/unmanaged type combination
```

I am guessing the first step to fix this is to change the return value to `IntPtr`, and i have tried it but i don't know how to convert the `IntPtr` to my Return[] value (and if this is the way at all)

Comment: The more simple solution would be to pass in an array to be filled from C# to C++.

Comment: I think C++ is a wrong tag here, this is about managed C++ right?

Comment: If you were to return the result to C# as an IntPtr, have you considered when that memory would be deallocated? I agree that passing in an array sounds like a better solution. @MarcoA. I don't think so, I think this is about interop from C# to C(++) via DllImport, which isn't managed C++.

Comment: Regarding your questions: Dont worry, my c# wrapper class dispoases of the data when i am done with it. About he suggestion of passing an array to be filled in my c++ code, can you write an example? Are there any other solutions? Please write here any code you think may help me. Thanks again!

Comment: Using the COM array format (a SAFEARRAY) is also possible.

Comment: Managed C++ is Visual Studio 2005 *only*, C++/CLI is code compiled with the `/CLR` flag to interop with .Net in later versions (in other words, you can't use *both*). This looks more like a P/Invoke of regular C++ code? If you *were* doing C++/CLI, you would just use a `ref class` and call it just like C# code.